# Why are elected representatives paid so much less than corporate top managers?

Tags: united-states, public-sector-compensation

As an example, the US president is getting around $400k per year. Meanwhile a CEO of a large corporation can easily get tens of millions of dollars per year. Likewise members of the US Senate are paid a lot less than board members of a typical multi-billion dollar corporations. Obviously elected officials have other ways of making money after retirement but usually they force them into a conflict of interests - e.g. the public speeches made by Senator Clinton before her presidential run.

So why aren't politicians getting a reasonable salary compared to their corporate counterparts? At the very least this would make them a lot less susceptible to corruption and at best it would attract people who wouldn't consider to run otherwise.

Comment: Does anyone have a reference for the claim that well renumerated people are less corrupt?

Comment: @origimbo Singapore pays nearly $2m to the Prime Minister in the hopes of preventing corruption. It seems reasonable to me that having a huge income in the first place would make bribes a lot less attractive.

Comment: @JonathanReez Italy pays its politics huge amounts of money and give them lot of privileges; with those, bribes are the icing on the cakes :-)

Comment: @JonathanReez if that were true then corporate bribery would only exist in relatively unprofitable companies since profitable companies run by wealthy individuals would have less incentive.  We know that to be categorically false since some of the most profitable entities in thw world have engaged in not just large scale corruption but *industrious global* corruption.

Comment: Another question this seems to be a duplicate of: [Why do politicians make so much money?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/13837/why-do-politicians-make-so-much-money?rq=1)

Comment: Because rich people don't pay the help more than they make.